# What determines the current directory in a web application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url

I have a MVC web application.
The start url is //foo/login/index.
On a view I show a picture images/bar.jpg.
The image is in de directory //foo/images

On my working station this works but when I install it on the test server the site can't find the image because it url to the image is:
//foo/login/images/bar.jpg instead of //foo/images/bar.jpg

So my current directory on my workstation differs from that on the test server.

My question: What determines the current directory in a mvc web application

Answer (score 1):

You probably have something like this in your View:

```
<img src="images/bar.jpg">
```

Replace it with:

```
<img src="~/images/bar.jpg">
```

The tilde or ~ character is resolved by the rendering engine at runtime to the root (home path) of your website.